# how to create an alert box using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I have tried to align the exclamation mark and I could not center it both vertically and horizontally, well my goal is to make it look the same as this image
[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
%-------------------------
\definecolor{orang}{RGB}{255,155,0}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{caja}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=orang,coltitle=orang,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=22mm,
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
    at ([xshift=-11mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {\Huge \centering  \textbf{!}};},
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}
%----------------------
\begin{document}
\section{example}

\begin{caja}[title=warning]
The vertical alignment settings are only relevant for boxes which are larger than their
natural height, see Section 4.10 on page 53.
\end{caja}
\end{document}
```

As you may have noticed, this **box has a title** and seems to have an effect on the alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting the anchor points, using `anchor=east` and getting rid of `\centering`as well as using `[xshift=-22.5pt]` produces the desired output.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%-------------------------
\definecolor{orang}{RGB}{255,155,0}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{caja}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=orang,coltitle=orang,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=22mm,
  % What you need %%%%%%%%%%%%
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=black,anchor=east]
  at ([xshift=-22.5pt]interior.base west) {\Huge  \textbf{!}};},
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}
%----------------------
\begin{document}
\section{example}

\begin{caja}[title=warning]
One-line text.
\end{caja}

\begin{caja}[title=warning]
The vertical alignment settings are only relevant for boxes which are larger than their natural height, see Section 4.10 on page 53.
\end{caja}

\begin{caja}[title=warning]
The vertical alignment settings are only relevant for boxes which are larger than their natural height, see Section 4.10 on page 53. The vertical alignment settings are only relevant for boxes which are larger than their natural height, see Section 4.10 on page 53. The vertical alignment settings are only relevant for boxes which are larger than their natural height, see Section 4.10 on page 53. 
\end{caja}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting,Thank you very much for your response, it has been a great help